# How to close a VB.NET application that is accesed by multiple pc on the same connection?

Tags: windows, vb.net

I have an application that I made in VB.NET. I put it in the server on my office and every other user access it via network connection. I only mapped the drive onto their computer and then I cope the shortcut to the application.
My question is can I close all the application that is running with a single code? I sometime need to close all the application first before I can do anything with the application (for example, modifying the report etc.). 
My current method is still the manual one, which is calling everyone to close their application or running all over the place closing the application myself.
Thank you for your time...

Answer (score 1):

ClickOnce deployment will make a local copy of the EXE for each user.

Otherwise put a timer in your app that checks a file e.g. SHUTDOWN.TXT. If SHUTDOWN.TXT exists, then the program shuts down and won't restart until the SHUTDOWN.TXT file is deleted.

Comment: I'll try that. But from what I know,the clickonce will only update the application on startup, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah I think that is true. So if you want to update the EXE while it is still running, you'll need to have some trigger, like the file being watched or something.